# Is there any Custom popup menu for iOS other than kxmenu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, popupmenu

Can any one suggest me custom `popup` menus for `iOS` which should be like [kxmenu](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu)

And I need something like this [screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6fqawlrc7pdhti/Screenshot.png)

And I need it to be expanadable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it for iPad or iPhone? iPads has a native pup up view, which you can just put a uitableview in

Comment: For iPhone... But i need something as it is in the screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a lot of PopOver View classes out there. take a look at

[Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

I'm using this one:

[TSPopover](https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover)

Comment: I searched for it, can you attach the links with your answer? I need custom classes as it is in the screen shot. Thank you.

Comment: just click on the text(Cocoa Controls or TSPopover), that are links :-)

Comment: I took a look at it. Is it expandable? I mean dynamically it should change in height and width since the content elements may have sub elements. is it possible?

Comment: read and learn :-) try it and if you then have questions you can ask here. but stackoverflow is no online course or tutorial :-)

Answer (score 2):

this also i have used in my code hope it will help you

[CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)

Comment: I dont need a tipView. I need something which is a menu.

Comment: @Gautham use this tip view and you can add some controllers insdie this view as per your requirements in my code i ahve use this and add textview according to my requirement.

Comment: Well I will look at it.